# Why does this for loop run infinitely?

Tags: c, for-loop, infinite-loop

I was trying a problem, where I had to write "Accept" for a string ending with b. I'm having trouble with this part of code:

```
char s[100];
int length,i=0;
gets(s);
length=strlen(s);
for( i=0; i<length; i+2)
{
  if(s[i]=='b' && s[i+1]=='\0')
      printf("Accept");
  else printf("Not accept");
}
```

But this loop runs infinitely.
The same problem is solved when I use this:

```
while(s[i]!='\0')
{ 
   if(s[i]=='b' && s[i+1]=='\0')
      printf("Accept");
   else printf("Not accept");
   i+2;
}
```

I understand there is a problem in the logic of the for loop, & have tried a lot to figure it out, but failed. I'm new to programming.Can you please help me with this.

Comment: There is a problem with the brackets

Comment: The while loop does work fine.

Comment: You are claiming that, when you use `i+2` at the end of your `while` loop, it runs fine and gives the right result? I guarantee you it does not; it will either not enter the loop at all (if `s[i]` for the initial value of `i` - both of which appear to be uninitialized in your `while` example - happens to be `0`) or stay in it indefinitely. It's at least `i += 2;` or `i = i + 2;`

Comment: Btw you are assuming that the null charcater is in an even position

Comment: @Ed Heal yes you are right. I've edited my question correcting the code.

Answer (score 5):

```
for( i=0; i<length; i+2)
```

`i` is not incremented. So it should be:

```
for( i=0; i<length; i+=2)
```

Answer (score 2):

You're not incrementing `i` in your `for` loop:

```
for( i=0; i<length; i+2)
```

All this does is add 2 to `i` and throws away the result.  You were probably intending to increment by 2, but that won't work either.  If your string contains an even number of characters, you'll never find the last character.

So what you need to do in increment by 1 on each iteration:

```
for( i=0; i<length; i++)
```

EDIT:

Better yet, just check the last character and get rid of the loop altogether:

```
if (s[length-1] == 'b') {
    printf("Accept\n");
} else {
    printf("Not Accept\n");
}
```

Comment: Actually, this is just a part of the code. I want to write a program where the string (ab)*b is accepted. So, I'm afraid, I can't use the logic you provided.

Comment: @dj1 If the string is `(ab)*b`, it will be accepted.  Try it.

Answer (score 2):

Where do you initialize your string? And also are you missing a parentheses? Also you probably want to print "Not accept" once. Check below for solution.

But really it will be much easier if you directly check the last character of array for 'b' (using as index `length-1`), and you don't need the loop anymore (since you know the length).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
int main()
{
  char s[100];
  strcpy(s,"test");
  int length = 0, i = 0, j = 0;
  length=strlen(s);
  for( i=0; i<length; i++)
  {
    if(s[i]=='b' && s[i+1]=='\0')
    {
       printf("Accept");
       j = 1;
    }

  }
  if(j==0) printf("Not accept");
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why have a `for` loop when the `strlen` has already done the work?

Comment: @EdHeal: I mentioned that in the comment, isn't it?

Comment: - Sorry I missed that

Answer (score 1):

In your `for` loop, you never incremented your `i` variable:

```
for( i=0; i<length; i+2) // should probably use i++ instead of i+2
```

Comment: I'm sure he doesn't mean i++

Comment: If i++ is used, the whole logic would change. I don't mean to use i++. I want to get the string which ends with b, get accepted.

Comment: @dj1: Why don't you just test `s[length-1]` directly and forget the loop?

Comment: @Blastfurnace Actually, this is just a part of the code. I want to write a program where the string (ab)*b is accepted. So, I'm afraid, I can't use the logic you provided.

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you are trying to solve (if I am reading the attempts correctly) is that you want to establish if the last character is the letter 'b'.

You have found out the length of the string by using:

```
length=strlen(s);
```

So using this fact you can do the following

```
if (length > 0 && s[length-1] == 'b') {
   printf("Accept");
}
else
{
   printf("Not accept");
}
```